# Escaping < & > between {{ }} without touching html

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, escaping

I am writing a templating engine in JS and need a hand with a regex.

I have a templates like this: 
`<div>{{#if 1 > 2}}show this {{/if}}</div>`

I am using node-htmlparser (https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) and finding that it works perfectly except for cases where < or > is between a pair of mustaches. I need to escape the < and > but only if they are between a pair of mustaches, leaving the rest of the html alone. I know this can be accomplished with a regex, but I do not know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it in two stages:

```
result = src.replace(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g,function(match) {
    return match.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
});
```

I haven't got any experience with Node, however, so I can't promise this'll work. It should, in theory!

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't work for `>`, only `<`

Answer (score 0):

I got some of this knowledge from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

I, like the first answer, found it simpler to do with two regexes:

```
var str = "<div>{{#if 1 > 2}}show this {{/if}}</div>";
var result = str.replace(/(\{\{.*?)<(.*?\}\})/, "$1&lt;$2");
result = str.replace(/(\{\{.*?)>(.*?\}\})/, "$1&gt;$2");
```

The `$1` in each represents the first capture group, and `$2` the second. The `<` or `>` are replaced with their escape text in each respectively.